# how to post data to table having foreignkey relation with user model using django rest api

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

i would like to add data to table which having a foreignkey relatonship with user model through django rest api.
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    # username = None
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',max_length=50,unique=True)
    phone =  models.CharField(max_length=17,blank=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone',
        'username',
    ]

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    medication = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

**serializers.py**

```
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer

class UserCreateSerializerCustom(UserCreateSerializer):
    
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta,):
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'email',
            'username',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phone',         
        )


## User Additional Info Serializers
class UserAdditionalSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserCreateSerializerCustom()
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = (
            'user',
            'address',
            'zipcode',
            'medication',
        )
```

**views.py**

```
class UserAdditionalView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):   
    queryset = UserInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserAdditionalSerializers
```

how will i send user instance with the data....??
i'm using token authentication  for the api. Which is the best way to achieve this..??

Comment: you're doing this for user `authentication` system ? or simply adding the user in your db ?

Comment: What i try to accomplish is that ,after registering the user i want another api for adding additional information.I'm building these api for the flutter app,After registration a page shows and tell the user to enter additiinal info .

Comment: If you're adding the additional information of the current user. you should obviously set the `permissions` for that only owner of the user or superuser can add the additional information itself.

Comment: I'm using token authentication for the user. The issue i'm facing is how to post data to table having foreign key. Can you suggest me any other question related to my need would be helpful.